# Doctrine Many to Many Query to get other side data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have many to many releationship between `institute` and `courses'.

```
class Institutes {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PNC\CoursesBundle\Entity\Courses", inversedBy="institutes")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="institute_courses",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="institute_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $courses;
}


class Courses {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes", mappedBy="courses")
     */
    protected $institutes;
}
```

I made a form to assign an institute multiple courses at onece and it works. Now i wanted to get those list of courses assign to the institute via doctrine query, i have below query, but id does not works.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('PNCInstitutesBundle:Institutes');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->innerJoin('i.courses', 'g')
            ->where('i.id = :inst_id')
            ->setParameter('inst_id',3)
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: often in doctrine Ive found it's much easier to build 2  many to one relationships with a bridge table between them, so 3 classes instead of 2,  Two of them are ManyToOne the one being the third class that is OneToMany to the other two.

Comment: In this join '->innerJoin('u.courses', 'g')' - given the alias 'u' is not defined anywhere (it should join off the 'i' alias), I don't think your example will even compile. - it should be '->innerJoin('i.courses', 'g')'

Answer (score 0):

```
 $repository = $em->getRepository('PNCCoursesBundle:Courses');
                $courses = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
                    ->innerJoin('i.institutes', 'g')
                    ->where('g.id = :inst_id')
                    ->setParameter('inst_id',$instituteID)
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```